# How to read fread values from gdb

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, decompiling

I have a C file (no source code) which I've decompiled, it reads two files and compares if it has the same content. I want to read the values for `data2`, in gdb, I've tried

```
(gdb)x/s 0x08048591
0x8048591 <main+52>:    "\215E\327\211\004$\350t\376\377\377\211E\370\203", <incomplete sequence \370>
```

For context:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    struct _IO_FILE * stream = popen("/bin/cat ~/.flag", "r"); // 0x8048572
    int32_t data;
    if (fread((char *)&data, 1, 32, stream) == 0) {
        // 0x80485a5
        perror("fread");
        // branch -> 0x8048682
        // 0x8048682
        return 1;
    }
    struct _IO_FILE * file = fopen("/var/level01/.flag", "r"); // 0x80485d5
    int32_t result; // 0x8048591_06
    int32_t data2;
    if (fread((char *)&data2, 1, 32, file) == 0) {
        // 0x8048608
        perror("fread");
        result = 1;
        // branch -> 0x8048682
    } else {
        // 0x804861b
        if (strcmp((char *)&data, (char *)&data2) == 0) {
            // 0x804863c
            execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh");
            // branch -> 0x8048658
        }
        // 0x8048658
        fwrite("Wrong password!\n", 1, 16, g1);
        result = 0;
        // branch -> 0x8048682
    }
    // 0x8048682
    return result;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure where to read and how to output this in gdb, any insight is appreciated.

Edit:

```
   0x0804855d <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804855e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048560 <+3>: sub    $0x5c,%esp
   0x08048563 <+6>: movl   $0x8048720,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804856b <+14>:    movl   $0x8048722,(%esp)
   0x08048572 <+21>:    call   0x80483e0 <popen@plt>
   0x08048577 <+26>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x0804857a <+29>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804857d <+32>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048581 <+36>:    movl   $0x20,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048589 <+44>:    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048591 <+52>:    lea    -0x29(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048594 <+55>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048597 <+58>:    call   0x8048410 <fread@plt>
   0x0804859c <+63>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804859f <+66>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x080485a3 <+70>:    jne    0x80485bb <main+94>
   0x080485a5 <+72>:    movl   $0x8048735,(%esp)
   0x080485ac <+79>:    call   0x80483f0 <perror@plt>
   0x080485b1 <+84>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x080485b6 <+89>:    jmp    0x8048682 <main+293>
   0x080485bb <+94>:    lea    -0x29(%ebp),%edx
   0x080485be <+97>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x080485c1 <+100>:   add    %edx,%eax
   0x080485c3 <+102>:   movb   $0x0,(%eax)
   0x080485c6 <+105>:   movl   $0x8048720,0x4(%esp)
   0x080485ce <+113>:   movl   $0x804873b,(%esp)
   0x080485d5 <+120>:   call   0x8048440 <fopen@plt>
   0x080485da <+125>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x080485dd <+128>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x080485e0 <+131>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x080485e4 <+135>:   movl   $0x20,0x8(%esp)
   0x080485ec <+143>:   movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
   0x080485f4 <+151>:   lea    -0x4a(%ebp),%eax
   0x080485f7 <+154>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080485fa <+157>:   call   0x8048410 <fread@plt>
   0x080485ff <+162>:   mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x08048602 <+165>:   cmpl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x08048606 <+169>:   jne    0x804861b <main+190>
   0x08048608 <+171>:   movl   $0x8048735,(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0804860f <+178>:   call   0x80483f0 <perror@plt>
   0x08048614 <+183>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048619 <+188>:   jmp    0x8048682 <main+293>
   0x0804861b <+190>:   lea    -0x4a(%ebp),%edx
   0x0804861e <+193>:   mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048621 <+196>:   add    %edx,%eax
   0x08048623 <+198>:   movb   $0x0,(%eax)
   0x08048626 <+201>:   lea    -0x4a(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048629 <+204>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804862d <+208>:   lea    -0x29(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048630 <+211>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048633 <+214>:   call   0x80483d0 <strcmp@plt>
   0x08048638 <+219>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0804863a <+221>:   jne    0x8048658 <main+251>
   0x0804863c <+223>:   movl   $0x0,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048644 <+231>:   movl   $0x8048759,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804864c <+239>:   movl   $0x8048759,(%esp)
   0x08048653 <+246>:   call   0x8048450 <execl@plt>
   0x08048658 <+251>:   mov    0x8049980,%eax
   0x0804865d <+256>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048661 <+260>:   movl   $0x10,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048669 <+268>:   movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048671 <+276>:   movl   $0x8048761,(%esp)
   0x08048678 <+283>:   call   0x8048400 <fwrite@plt>
   0x0804867d <+288>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048682 <+293>:   leave  
   0x08048683 <+294>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Why not to print `data2` variable in gdb ?

Comment: @ks1322 the challenge does not let me compile/execute this source code or move/copy the two files it reads. The only option I have is to gdb the output file (with no source code). The idea would be to print it, but I can't even list in gdb so no idea what to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've decompiled,

It is very likely that you made a mistake. If this was correct decompilation:

```
int32_t data;
if (fread((char *)&data, 1, 32, stream) == 0) {
```

then the program would be "guilty" of stack overflow (`fread` tries to read 32 bytes, but you've only provided space for 32 *bits* (i.e. only 4 bytes)).

More likely the correct decompilation is something like:

```
char data[32];
if (fread(data, 1, 32, stream) == 0) {
```

> I want to read the values for data2, in gdb, I've tried
>    `(gdb)x/s 0x08048591`

As GDB shows you, the address `0x08048591` is inside `main` and is part of program *code*.

You want to examine *data* (or stack) of the program, and for that you need to use `x/s` on the correct address.

Unfortunately you didn't provide the *actual* assembly of the program, so we can't tell you what that correct address should be.

**Update:**

The disassembly for second `fread` is:

```
0x080485f4 <+151>:   lea    -0x4a(%ebp),%eax
0x080485f7 <+154>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080485fa <+157>:   call   0x8048410 <fread@plt>
```

This tells us that the data is in fact on stack, and to look at the data one would use:

```
x/s $ebp-0x4a
```

while stopped at instruction at `0x08048602` (i.e. after `fread` has returned).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought it would be too much, i've added the assembly code for the main

Comment: I get 0xbffff69e:<incomplete sequence \345\267>. I tried using breakpoints at main, at those address and at each "next". Any ideas?

Comment: @user153882 I've updated the answer. 1. You (*obviously*) need to look at the data only after `fread` has returned. 2. The data *may* be binary, depending on what's in the file, so "incomplete sequence" doesn't imply that there is any problem.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me immensely